# "Enable As Partner" option not available for Account in Lightning view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, account

"Enable As Partner" option not available for Account in Lightning view. Is this not supported in Lightning right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's not available yet:
*Features Not Available in Lightning Experience: Account partners*

You can have a look to the Sales Cloud features still missing [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_sales.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Not currently supported out of the box, but there looks to be an app for this on the AppExchange at no cost.  I have not used it myself, you can review it here:  https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFp8sUAD